# How build up an object without using casts or creating variables for every field?

Tags: typescript

[Here's an example you can play with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBLA5gFWagXjgG8AoOOAMwggC44A7AVwFsAjYKAbgvLjYCGUAPz1m7Tlz6CAXmNYdufAI5MQouAGcYUDAywBtALpSAvlNKUmDAMYwMEBuiYYANgBNMufAAowQgRZNem1dfWMAShI%20CgB6WLgACU5gAHJNOAB3AAsBeABJVPc4VwwAa1QYCDh3Ohi4G0dtOGAGdwAlYE0mVxh6LzwUOCJic1J6%20M0IFlRXCCwMGypoOCxgGHt9ZYh61o6unpgAOmpqogBWCwo42KmZkvnF5ahV9c2sfiFdts7u3qPBC8iNZ3MBKHpgO4rtd4kc4eNrnAoOsmFAnHtfoczEA). Here's what that code looks like:

```
export type BigType = {
  foo: number;  
  bar?: number;
  baz: number;
  qux?: string[];
};

function BuildBigType(params: string[]) {
    // Here's what I'd like to do:
    const endResult: BigType = {};

    //some logic for getting foo
    endResult.foo = 5;

    //some logic for getting bar
    endResult.bar = undefined;

    //...

    return endResult;
}
```

This doesn't compile because `{}` isn't a `BigType`. I can think of two workarounds:

1. Cast `endResult` to `any` and assign the fields like the example already shows.
2. Create local variable for every BigType field, then assign it at the end of the function. e.g.,

   ```
     //...
     return {foo, bar, baz, qux};
   }
   ```

Are there any other options?

Comment: Factory pattern as per option 2 and simply add the output type to the function so you get the type benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [lazy object initialization](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/lazyobjectliteralinitialization), which isn't directly supported in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#28503](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28503) for the open feature request, and maybe give it a  if you want to see this happen.

---

The easiest way to change the code so that it there are no errors but isn't as unsafe as using `any` is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (what you're calling "casting") to say `endResult` is a `BigType` when you declare it:

```
function BuildBigTypeAssert(params: string[]) {
  const endResult = {} as BigType;
  endResult.foo = 5;
  endResult.bar = undefined;
  return endResult; // okay, but oops I forgot baz
}
```

That's a reasonable approach (and is listed in the doc linked at the top of this answer) but the drawback is that the compiler will not catch an error where you forget to initialize a property.  You can see that I forgot to initialize `baz`, but the compiler did not warn.  Whenever you use a type assertion, you need to be careful.

---

Another approach is to emulate lazy initialization with an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) instead of a direct property assignments:

```
function setProp<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey, V>(
  obj: T, key: K, val: V
): asserts obj is T & { [P in K]: V } {
  (obj as any)[key] = val;
}
```

The `setProp()` function takes an object, a key, and a value, and a new property to the object with the specified key and value.  The return type tells the compiler that after you call `setProp(obj, key, val)`, the type of `obj` has been extended.  So instead of writing `obj[key] = val`, you write `setProp(obj, key, val)`, and suddenly you get the sort of expando typing you were looking for:

```
function BuildBigType(params: string[]): BigType {
  const endResult = {};
  setProp(endResult, "foo", 5);
  setProp(endResult, "bar", undefined);
  setProp(endResult, "baz", 123);
  return endResult; // okay
}
```

Here I've annotated that `BuildBigType` returns a `BigType`, and I let the compiler infer that `endResult` is of type `{}` when I declare it.  After each call to `setProp()`, the type of `endResult` is extended.  The fact that `return endResult` compiles with no warning is evidence that we didn't make a mistake.  If you forget a property, you get an error:

```
function BuildBigTypeError(params: string[]): BigType {
  const endResult = {};
  setProp(endResult, "foo", 5);
  setProp(endResult, "bar", undefined);
  return endResult; // error! Property 'baz' is missing
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBLA5gFWagXjgG8AoOOAMwggC44A7AVwFsAjYKAbnLjYEMoAfnrN2nHhQEAvUaw7deARyYgRcAM4woGBlgDaAXR4BfHqUpMGAYxgYIDTcBgAFKBDAAeHHFAxgDAAmGnAQbABWwLYANHAA0r4g-kEhbh6cSHHAiLEAagB8ABS8YeH0OLEA1tn0cbEAbvwANvS5pACU9PwaGhkhpXAYIT4AZCRw+i6DjnGGrXAmJLyFA91w-AyI7frViIZwRI1NpqQWVrb2jmhMGE2BmLj4AII9GYVggvwsGvRaOnpGTrobB4FBLCjWBxaXxBABKwA0TCa8CIxEWaweoOAkhhgXhiORADpqBADnAAKw4gJ4hFImCEgRQMlWQLASi6YCBHFQZxMKCOan4ulcOAAelFoUq-ByfCY8BoYBCAEkqNAsBB4DJSCZTpYbHYHOgbndMfh3p9vr9tLoDIYgaawWQIVD4ILaciyWicb1XO4wIU3QSYLEAEQkkOxcntb3ONL+wN00OMiNwFlsjmBaO8H1xgNw93BuAhmQpgCMACYAMxZig8mB8gX5oMi8WS6Xa05nfWXI23e4g-AAUSg7ig5qgXx+mmtALt9AdqCdcEhDGhCY9qLM2djfrzNKDofDkZrTl9Hj3QuRScEKbT7IYnJPdYbuMvMBbEs4o4AhHA4xlEDgAByGQgMGEIWCGDQbW1IA)

Answer (score 3):

There's not a really super elegant way around it. I would recommend option 2., because type inferences will work relatively nicely together and you only have to assemble the full type at the end when you return. You can optionally set the return type of your function to help enforce it and prevent you from making a mistake.

```
function BuildBigType(params: string[]): BigType {
    //some logic for getting foo
    const foo = 5;

    //some logic for getting bar
    const bar = undefined;

    //...

    return {foo, bar, baz, qux};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build up this object in two parts. First, build a required field object. then create `endResult: BigType` and populate optional fields.

```
export function BuildBigType(params: string[]): BigType {
  // Build required fields first
  const requiredFields = { foo: null, baz: null };
  requiredFields.foo = 5;
  requiredFields.baz = 10;

  const endResult: BigType = { ...requiredFields };
 
  // Build optional fields
  endResult.bar = undefined;

  return endResult;
}
```